# create a new column based on a list column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to create a new column based on the value of a list column. If a column value contains a specific string like high, HIGH, Important etc., the new column should contain the value as High/Important

```
id         specification
123 ['high', 'Important', 'pilot']
234 ['HIGH', 'Important', 'Baby']
543 ['important']
542 ['week']
857 ['new', 'IMPORTANT']
123 ['super_high' 'test']
```

My expected new_col is

```
id      specification                 new_col    
123 ['high', 'Important', 'pilot']  High/Important
234 ['HIGH', 'Important', 'Baby']   High/Important
543 ['important']                   High/Important
542 ['week'] 
857 ['new', 'IMPORTANT']            High/Important
123 ['super_high' 'test']           High/Important
```

As the column 'specification' contains list value .str.contains() will not work. Is there any way we can achieve in pandas

Answer (score 1):

To match full words, use a list comprehension with a search in a `set`:

```
labels = {'high', 'important'}

df['new_col'] = ['High/Important' if
                   any(x.lower() in labels for x in l)
                 else '' for l in df['specification']]
```

Output:

```
    id             specification         new_col
0  123  [high, Important, pilot]  High/Important
1  234   [HIGH, Important, Baby]  High/Important
2  543               [important]  High/Important
3  542                    [week]                
4  857          [new, IMPORTANT]  High/Important
5  123          [super_hightest]
```

To match substrings:

```
labels = ['high', 'important']
df['new_col'] = ['High/Important' if
                   any(w in x for x in map(str.lower, l) for w in labels)
                 else '' for l in df['specification']]
```

Or with a regex match:

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['specification'].apply(' '.join)
                          .str.lower()
                          .str.contains('high|important'),
                         'High/Important', '')
```

Output:

```
    id             specification         new_col
0  123  [high, Important, pilot]  High/Important
1  234   [HIGH, Important, Baby]  High/Important
2  543               [important]  High/Important
3  542                    [week]                
4  857          [new, IMPORTANT]  High/Important
5  123          [super_hightest]  High/Important
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [123, 234, 543, 542, 857, 123],
                   'specification': [['high', 'Important', 'pilot'],
                                     ['HIGH', 'Important', 'Baby'],
                                     ['important'],
                                     ['week'],
                                     ['new', 'IMPORTANT'],
                                     ['super_hightest']]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, consider creating a new column using a helper function and `apply`.

```
import re

# helper function substring match
def high_important(specs):
    spec_string = "".join(specs)
    
    if re.findall(r"high|important", spec_string, re.IGNORECASE):
        return "High/Important"
    else:
        return ""

# new column based on existing df["specification"]
df["new_col"] = df.apply(
        lambda df: high_important(df["specification"]), 
        axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
    id             specification         new_col
0  123  [high, Important, pilot]  High/Important
1  234   [HIGH, Important, Baby]  High/Important
2  543               [important]  High/Important
3  542                    [week]                
4  857          [new, IMPORTANT]  High/Important
5  123        [super_high, test]  High/Important
```